# Simple drop down menu from link?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I need to create a simple drop down from a link. When the user clicks a hyperlink, the drop down will appear.

The menu part will have a gradient.  It doesn't need any hover effects.  It will have several clickable items.  There are no buttons or any other decorations involved.

Does anyone have an example of how to create this type of drop down?

Comment: are you talking about left or right clicking a hyperlink? and would you be willing to use javascript?

Comment: Yes - left clicking a hyperlink.  I was looking for a pure CSS solution but I think JS is needed instead?  That is ok if so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want solution with jQuery involved, here is an example.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#">Click me!</a>
<ul>
    <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: none;
}

ul li a {
    display: block;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
        $(this).next().toggle();
    });
});
```

Here is demo http://jsfiddle.net/qrQR8/

---

If you want pure CSS solution (based on your tags on the question), here is example using checkbox.

**HTML**

```
<label for="trigger">Click me!</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="trigger" name="trigger"/>
<ul>
    <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: none;
}

input[name=trigger] {
    display: none;
}

ul li a {
    display: block;
}

label {
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[name=trigger]:checked + ul {
    display: block;
}
```

And here is demo http://jsfiddle.net/qrQR8/1/

---

You can use and benefits of `:target` selector, but you can't hide again menu after click.

http://jsfiddle.net/qrQR8/2/

Comment: This is cool.  Thanks.  Do you have some suggestions for applying a gradient to the menu?

Comment: @4thSpace, here you can find a tool for making background gradients http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/. Get your code for background gradient, and apply it on `ul` element.

Comment: Thanks.  For the :target example, what is the benefit you mention?  Why would someone use that example over the other?

Comment: Well there are no benefits over jQuery solutions :) I've meant - benefetis of this selector if you want to use pure css solution. Of course, jQuery solution is the best in this case.

Comment: Ok but why is jQuery better?  They seem to function the same.

Comment: In your current HTML markup it is the same, but CSS selectors can select element only if they are inside same parent. Also, without jQuery, you must create that hidden checkbox for each menu.

Comment: Thanks.  One thing I've noticed is that the menu pushes down all page content.  Is there a way to make the menu overlap or appear on top of other page items rather than pushing them down?  I can create a new question for this if you'd like.

Comment: @4thSpace, simply add `position: absolute;` to `ul`. http://jsfiddle.net/qrQR8/3/

Answer (score 1):

here's a javascript solution:

Javascript:

```
$( "#link" ).mousedown( function( ){

    $( this ).next( ).show( 100 );
});
```

HTML:

```
<div>
<div id="link">Click me</div>
    <div syle="display:none">

        <div>This item</div>
        <div>That item</div>
        <div>Other item</div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use the [jQuery Superfish Menu](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-superfish-menus-plugin/).

It has a nice smooth effect, and it is even compatible with IE6 (yes, unfortunately there are some ugly projects - YES, UGLY -, that need to be compatible with).

Changing it's CSS is incredibly easy. It is an highly customizable plugin.

Comment: Way overkill for what I'm looking for.

Comment: Why overkill? It is a lightweight library.

Comment: See the OP.  I'm looking for something simple that goes off a hyperlink.  Superfish is neither.